# Getting time in milliseconds on ARM MCU with long data type of 4 bytes

Tags: c, time

I am looking to get time in milliseconds however I am using an ARM MCU where `long` and `time_t` are of 4 bytes size, which means the following approach wouldn't work. Are there any workarounds?

```
static inline long EpochTimeInMs()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    long ms = (tv.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv.tv_usec) / 1000; 
    return ms;
}
```

Comment: You could use something like long long or uint64_t.

Comment: Can you use `long long`? The epoch time in milliseconds is never going to fit a 32-bit variable even for a single year.

Comment: I tried `long long` but values don't match up

Comment: Cast before the arithmetic is done. `long long ms = (long long)tv.tv_sec * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000; `

Comment: `an ARM MCU` Are you _sure_ that your "ARM MCU" system has `gettimeofday` implemented? What is the return value of the function?

Comment: How does any of this make sense on an MCU? Do you have an external RTC and battery backup or what?

Comment: @WeatherVane casting like this did the trick. Is it totally safe though?

Comment: There are on average about 31557600000 millseconds in one year. So 2^63 over that gives nearly 300000 years.

Comment: uh, sorry 300000000 years.